# Strange brown winged insect on nectarine

Tags: identification, insects, nectarines

I was picking fruit the other day and saw this large bug, just about an inch long I want to say, perched on top of one of the nectarines near the top of the tree. Anyone know what it is and what kind of damage it can produce?

It flew away when I drew near, not a zippy flyer like a fly but sort of slow in its motion.

[image: close up of insect]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called a leaf footed bug.  The exact species will depend on your location but I'm leaning toward *Leptoglossus clypealis* since your profile says you live in San Francisco.  You can read more about the three species found in California, their life cycle, damage to plants and management suggestions [here](http://ipm.ucanr.edu/PMG/PESTNOTES/pn74168.html).

They feed by probing into plants and sucking out the juices from leaves and fruits.  The damage is relatively minor however on fruits like your nectarines they can cause dislocations and depressions as the fruits grow.  They are also known to feed on tomatoes and can cause very small tomatoes to stop growing but don't normally harm large tomatoes in any noticeable way.  In low populations no management is needed however you can hand pick adults and larvae and place in a bucket of soapy water to reduce their impact on your plants.